# why am i getting records of year 2014,2015 up to may 2016 while executing this query >

Tags: sql

```
select t1.InvoiceNumber ,t1.LocalAmount  , t2.LineAmount as discount , t1.CreateDate
from CashOrderTrn t1 
left join DistrubutedDiscountDetails t2 
    on t1.InvoiceNumber =  t2.InvoiceNumber  
    and t1.CreateDate between '20160531' and  '20160701' 
    and t1.InvoiceType ='31'
```

Comment: Column t1.CreateDate's data type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the t1 conditions to the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t1.InvoiceNumber ,t1.LocalAmount , t2.LineAmount as discount ,
      t1.CreateDate
from CashOrderTrn t1
left join DistrubutedDiscountDetails t2 on t1.InvoiceNumber = t2.InvoiceNumber
WHERE t1.CreateDate between '20160531' and '20160701' and t1.InvoiceType ='31'
```

BTW, are you storing dates in a character column? I'd recommend a `date` column instead.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, nope, t1, not t2.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Not so, both conditions in that `where` apply to the first table, `t1`